# How to visualize natural atomic orbitals from PySCF

Tags: visualization-software, orbitals, pyscf, avogadro

I'm trying to visualize the different methods of getting localized orbital (LO) given in the [User Guide](https://pyscf.org/user/lo.html).  I went through the example, saved the orbitals as cube files, then opened the files in Avogadro to visualize.  However, most of the occupied orbitals don't look localized at all so I think I'm doing something wrong.  The code I'm using is below.  I also tried to parallel the [example code for generating cube files](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/master/examples/local_orb/04-ibo_benzene_cubegen.py):

```
import numpy as np
from pyscf import gto, scf, lo
from pyscf.tools import cubegen

x = .63
mol = gto.M(atom=[['C', (0, 0, 0)],
                  ['H', (x ,  x,  x)],
                  ['H', (-x, -x,  x)],
                  ['H', (-x,  x, -x)],
                  ['H', ( x, -x, -x)]],
            basis='ccpvtz')
mf = scf.RHF(mol).run()

# C matrix stores the AO to localized orbital coefficients
C = lo.orth_ao(mf, 'nao')
orbs = C[:,mf.mo_occ>0] # Only get occupied orbitals

for i in range(orbs.shape[1]):
    cubegen.orbital(mol, f'ch4_nao_mo{i+1}.cube', orbs[:,i])
```

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Just to clarify, could you include an image of one/some of the not localized orbitals? I would assume there is only so much localization that can be done for a molecule as small as methane.

Comment: I added the images of the orbitals. Besides the first one, the occupied orbitals aren't localized.

Comment: I'd guess the first one is the 1s atomic orbital on carbon, which is heavily localized even under the standard AO scheme. I agree, these are the canonical MOs, not the localized orbitals.

Comment: Wow, 270 views despite no answers and not appearing on the HNQ list? I wonder if this was advertised somewhere like on Twitter or a mailing list, or if it just came up in an  *unusually* large number of search engine results. Also, have you figured out the answer now Steve? What Geoff's comment helpful? It would be nice to have this out of the unanswered queue now that it's been more than 7 months!

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP responds to questions/suggestions in the comments.